Todo list using array and loop
I want to create a todo list using array and loop and display the list in div container. I am able to display the list but it is muliplying the same list stored and is displayed.
<body>
    <p class="title"> Todo List </p>
    <input type="text" class="js-input-todo" placeholder="Todo name">
    <button type="submit" class="js-btn-todo" onclick="handleAddTodo()">Add</button>

    <div class="todo-list"></div>

 <script src="script/11-arrays-loop.js"></script>
</body>

//script 

let names = []

let todoListHTML = ''

function handleAddTodo(){
  const todo_input = document.querySelector('.js-input-todo');
  const todoValue = todo_input.value
  const result = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
 
  names.push(todoValue);
  for(let i = 0; i <  names.length ; i++){
   let todoName = names[i]
   const html = `<p>${todoName} </p>`
   todoListHTML = html;
   result.innerHTML +=todoListHTML;
   
   todo_input.value = '';
  }
  
  

}

I want to the array value to not repeat and displayed in the output

Because every time you add one item, you loop over the entire list again and append every item to the HTML… Just don’t do that?

Since you are using JavaScript in the browser, you can use document.createElement to create a node and use textContent instead of innerHTML. This way you don't have to sanitize the text to be inserted for unwanted HTML code that can break your page.

Try this ,
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <script>
        let names = [];
        let todoListHTML = ''

function handleAddTodo(){
  const todo_input = document.querySelector('.js-input-todo').value;
  const todoValue = todo_input.value
  const result = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
 
  names.push(todoValue); 
   const html = `<p>${todo_input} </p>`
   todoListHTML = html;
  result.innerHTML +=todoListHTML;
  todo_input.value = '';
}
</script>

<body>
    <p class="title"> Todo List </p>
    <input type="text" class="js-input-todo" placeholder="Todo name">
    <button type="submit" class="js-btn-todo" onclick="handleAddTodo()">Add</button>

    <div class="todo-list"></div>

 </body>
</html>



 you need to make that div empty before starting the For-loop.
add this result.innerHTML = ' '  before For-loop.


let names = [];
let todoListHTML = ''

function handleAddTodo(){
     
     const todo_input = document.querySelector('.js-input-todo')
     const todoValue = todo_input.value
     const result = document.querySelector('.todo-list')

     result.innerHTML = ''
     names.push(todoValue)

     for(let i = 0; i <  names.length ; i++){

          let todoName = names[i]
          const html = `<p>${todoName}</p>`
          todoListHTML = html
          result.innerHTML +=todoListHTML
          todo_input.value = ''
     }

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title"> Todo List </p>
    <input type="text" class="js-input-todo" placeholder="Todo name">
    <button type="submit" class="js-btn-todo" onclick="handleAddTodo()">Add</button>

    <div class="todo-list"></div>

 </body>
</html>



base on your code i think you are new to programing. i recommend you to use an IDE(vs code) for better code formatting.
you don't really need a loop for that.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<script>

let names = [];
let todoListHTML = ''

function handleAddTodo(){

     const todo_input = document.querySelector('.js-input-todo')
     const todoValue = todo_input.value
     const result = document.querySelector('.todo-list')


     names.push(todoValue)

     let todoName = names[names.length-1]
     const html = `<p>${todoName}</p>`
     result.innerHTML +=html
     todo_input.value = ''
}

</script>


<body>
    <p class="title"> Todo List </p>
    <input type="text" class="js-input-todo" placeholder="Todo name">
    <button type="submit" class="js-btn-todo" onclick="handleAddTodo()">Add</button>

    <div class="todo-list"></div>

 </body>
</html>




    const names = [];
    const result = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
    const todo_input = document.querySelector(".js-input-todo");
    function handleAddTodo() {
      const todoValue = todo_input.value;
      const html = document.createElement("p");
      html.innerHTML = todoValue;
      result.append(html);
      names.push(todoValue);
      todo_input.value = "";
      console.log(names, "names");
    }


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
